# Exele chart zoom on click

Tags: excel, charts

I would like to know if there is a way so that I can click on a chart and then it will automatically zoom in on or make the chart biger while I am clicked on the chart .

I need this because on my dashboard I have multiple charts that I made smaller to fit on the screen without scrolling down

Comment: **OPTION1** Write a macro to resize the chart. Right click on the chart and assign that macro. **OPTION2 (My fav)** Write a macro to launch a userform and then show the chart in the userform. Add +/- button to give more flexibility to zoom in and out. Right click on the chart and assign that macro.

Comment: The [Camera tool](https://trumpexcel.com/excel-camera-tool/) can be useful here combined with macros.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.